# mysql rows from select tag of html, option all of these

Tags: mysql

table like this

```
 id_film  |  ID_ZANER 

195       |      1 

195       |      4 

155       |      4
```

....

of 20 mil. rows

my query is

```
SELECT id_film 
FROM csfd_zanre_odkazy 
where ID_ZANER in (1,4) 
group by id_film having count(*)=2
```

this select id_film = 195, but i have many rows and this query is slow and non effective.

can you help me

Comment: Can you please show us the results of `EXPLAIN SELECT id_film FROM csfd_zanre_odkazy where ID_ZANER in (1,4) group by id_film having count(*)=2;` ?

Comment: 20 million rows? What's a zaner?

Comment: here is screen http://imgur.com/2vLdHUX of explain 

zaner=genre , sorry its slovak language, but its just label

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "DISTINCT" after "SELECT" on your query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_film FROM csfd_zanre_odkazy where ID_ZANER in (1,4) group by id_film having count(*)=2
```

Comment: distinct has no effect when i make group by on that column

Comment: you just select one column, why you still need group by? I guess it should not.

Comment: because i need count(*)=2 with distinct i cant do that

Answer (score 0):

You should create an index on `ID_ZANER` and `id_film`:

```
CREATE INDEX test_idx
          ON csfd_zanre_odkazy (ID_ZANER, id_film);
```

Comment: off course i have this index but group by and having on so many records is pretty slow

Comment: Would it be possible to add other tables and triggers to store precalculated data and speedup your query?

Comment: Yes it is used, name is ID_ZANER_2, time of query is pretty fast but not enough, how you see in explain index working, but there is  temporary and sorting,  also this query making group by and having which has for example: 1 mil rows and after group by and having is 0.3 mil.. but i thing its can be more effective query

Comment: Ok, I see... Well, it is a problem I don't know ho to solve... I'll check back your question in some days to see if there's a correct answer... I'm curious about how to do it...